# Channel vs Connection in netty

Tags: netty, nio

Hi I am new to jBoss netty.I was doing a sample using `ClientBootStrap` and `ServerBootStrap` and both of them posses individual `ChannelFactory` instances.

My confusion is that when the client connect to server, is this **connection** called the `Channel` ? or the client and server sides will keep separate `Channel`s and client `Channel` connect to Server `Channel`?.

Can anyone clarify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection is between the two channels. The word 'channel' comes from NIO, and it's a poor choice, when you think about it. 'Socket' expresses it better: it's an *endpoint* of a connection.

Comment: Thanks. So SimpleChannelHandler.channelConnected() will be invoked whenever a new (say client) channel connected to the current channel to which the handler is attached. is this right?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm no authority on Netty., can't answer that.

Comment: channelConnected(...) will be called once a new connection was established.

Comment: So, can I think that if I have x channels instances, then I have x tcp connections if I am using netty to transform data in tcp ?

Comment: @Jaskey Only if they are all connected.